# Iterate a collection of models to save multiple records in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, foreach

I've this POST action result which receive two models one from main View and the other from the Partial View 
 the model that comes from main view is fine as it will post only one record at a time the issue is with the model that I POST method receive from Partial View as it is sending multiple records at a time, My question is How can I loop through the model that is coming from partial View so that I can save all records instead of just one 
Here is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(ViewModels model)
    {
        var pecEquipmentRequest = new PECEquipmentRequest()
        {
            ProjectId = model.ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel.ProjectId,
            JobNo = model.ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel.JobNo,
            RequestDate = model.ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel.RequestDate
        };
        db.PECEquipmentRequests.Add(pecEquipmentRequest);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //foreach (int items in model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Id.ToString())
        //{

       // }

        var pecEquipmentRequestDetail = new PECEquipmentRequestDetail()
        {
            EquipmentRequestId = pecEquipmentRequest.Id,
            EquipmentId = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Id,
            Planned = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Planned,
            Actual = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Actual,
            // Remarks = model.ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel.Remarks
        };
        db.PECEquipmentRequestDetails.Add(pecEquipmentRequestDetail);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

**This section needs a loop**

```
    var pecEquipmentRequestDetail = new PECEquipmentRequestDetail()
    {
        EquipmentRequestId = pecEquipmentRequest.Id,
        EquipmentId = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Id,
        Planned = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Planned,
        Actual = model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[0].Actual,
        // Remarks = model.ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel.Remarks
    };
    db.PECEquipmentRequestDetails.Add(pecEquipmentRequestDetail);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**

The `ModelEquipmentRequestResult` property is a `List<EquipmentRequest_Result>`.

My ViewModel class is:

```
public class ViewModels
{
    public EquipmentSpViewModel ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<EquipmentRequest_Result> ModelEquipmentRequestResult { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your model and the view (if you using a partial, its unlikely its going to bind correctly anyway unless you passing the `HtmlFieldPrefix`)

Comment: What does the `ViewModels` class object look like, please share that code.

Comment: @DavidPine please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I loop through the model that is coming from partial View so that I can save all records instead of just one Here is my code.

You're looking to utilize a [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop. You will need to have a collection that implements either the `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` interface(s). The syntax for the iteration is rather straightforward.

Use the `foreach` keyword, then enclose the iterator expression within the open/close parenthesis `(iterator expression)` like so:

```
foreach (var value in model.SomeKnownCollection)
{
    // At this point, the variable namely "value" is one of the values in the collection
    // And this snippet of code will be executed "for each" value in the collection...
}
```

Does that make sense? Since the `ViewModels` class property that we're trying to iterate over is of type `List<T> where T : EquipmentRequest_Result` this will not be an issue at all.

```
foreach (var result in model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult)
{
   // We add to the details a new instance of the "pecEquipmentRequestDetail"
   // From the "result" in the collection...
   db.PECEquipmentRequestDetails.Add(
       new pecEquipmentRequestDetail
       {
           EquipmentRequestId = pecEquipmentRequest.Id,
           EquipmentId = result .Id,
           Planned = result .Planned,
           Actual = result .Actual
       });
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Using [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) however, this could be simplified by using a `Select` and `AddRange`:

```
db.PECEquipmentRequestDetails.AddRange(
    model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult
         .Select(result => new pecEquipmentRequestDetail
       {
           EquipmentRequestId = pecEquipmentRequest.Id,
           EquipmentId = result .Id,
           Planned = result .Planned,
           Actual = result .Actual
       }));
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks love it was very helpful